# UDP server fails to respond multiple request.

Tags: c#, .net, router, serversocket

I am using some functionality and developed UDP server to access request from multiple device simultaneously  .my server code handle the request and process the request using some business logic with SQL database and response back the device from which he received.and this whole process work on WIFI network.this is working good when there are approx 15-20 device but when device are increase (50-60) than it fail to response.can any one tell me about this issue. Thanks

Comment: "Guess what's wrong with my code. I'm not going to show you any of it.". No, that's not going to work. Please try to create a [mcve].

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to even hazard a guess at the cause. All we know is that a) your code uses UDP (so does a **lot** of code), b) You've got some kind of SQL database (so does a **lot** of code), and c) You're using a WiFi network (so do a **lot** of people). Those items, even in combination, are not *rare*. So you need to provide more information. Ideally, as a code *sample* that actually exhibits the problem you're talking about.